# How to create Multilevel Numbered Headings in word document by using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, wordprocessingml

I would like to create word document by using C# and library named "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing".
However, I have a problem about numbering and creating multilevel headings.

The target result is like the following example.

**Example :**

1. Chapter 1

   *1.1.* Chapter 1.1.

   *1.2.* Chapter 1.2.
2. Chapter 2

   *2.1.* Chapter 2.1.

**But the result that I have is like this :**

1. Chapter 1

   *1.* Chapter 1.1.

   *2.* Chapter 1.2.
2. Chapter 2

   *1.* Chapter 2.1.

I used NumberingLevelReference() to adjust heading number but the result is not right.

Please suggest parameter or something that I need to add.
Thanks for your help and I apologize for my english.